# insert arabic letter in mysql field RLT

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, arabic

i have problem in mysql field is " the class name " I'm Arabic man so our class name 
like that :**11D2** assume that D is Arabic letter , but I'm mysql field it appears like that "112D" cuz my Arabic language start from Right to left .

so i want to ask how to fix it and store it like **11D2**

```
CREATE TABLE `class` (
 `CLASS_ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `CLASS_NAME` varchar(45) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `Grade_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `Stage_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `school_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`CLASS_ID`),
 KEY `school_ids3` (`school_id`),
 KEY `grade_ids` (`Grade_id`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `stage_ids2` (`Stage_id`) USING BTREE,
  CONSTRAINT `grade_id4` FOREIGN KEY (`Grade_id`) REFERENCES `grade` (`Grade_id`) ON     DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
 CONSTRAINT `school_id8` FOREIGN KEY (`school_id`) REFERENCES `schools` (`school_id`)    ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
CONSTRAINT `stage_id3` FOREIGN KEY (`Stage_id`) REFERENCES `stage` (`STAGE_ID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
 )     ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=20 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: it is already stored as 11d2, maybe your question how to display it the same way?

Comment: not , it stored as 112d , assume D is Arabic letter .

Comment: or yes i want to store it in right way and display it in right way .

Comment: why do you think it is stored wrong? are you looking at some output?

Comment: it stored ok , but how to display it right ? in phpmyadmin

Comment: so, phpmyadmin outputs it wrong, but it does not mean that it is stored wrong, use direct methods (via console or php) to check exactly value in db

Comment: Are you inserting in phpmyadmin or elsewhere?

Comment: yes phpmyadmin no else